# Standard objects as details in an MDR

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Why does SF prohibit STD objects on the detail side of an MDR? I think you can have the same level of complex relationships with custom objects. The only thing I can think of is that it has to do with multi-tennant environment and deletion, meaning that say contacts/etc from all companies that use SF have their contacts* in the same table and if they were a detail in a MDR, then it would effect other companies.